# Loop through colors and plot sns.distplot()

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, matplotlib, plot

Can someone spot the really quick fix to my problem? I'm trying to plot two distributions on the same figure using the Seaborn package. I'd like for one line to be red and the other blue. The way I have my for-loop set up now only produces blue lines. X and Y are 1-d arrays with data that I am plotting.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

colors = ['r','b']

for a in [x, y]:
    for i in range(2):
        sns.distplot(a, bins=range(1, 25, 1), ax=ax,
        kde=True, hist=False, color=colors[i])
```

Comment: your loop doesn't make sense, try collapsing into one loop `for i, a in enumerate([x, y]):`

Comment: Yeah I really bad at loops. When I do `for i, a in [x, y]:
    sns.distplot(a, bins=range(1, 25, 1), ax=ax,
    kde=True, hist=False, color=colors[i])` then I get the error `ValueError: too many values to unpack`

Comment: @daryl thanks for your initial comment. Any other tips?

Comment: The comment by daryl is correct. You just need to use it.